# php preg_split, "nothing to repeat" error

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

I need to split string with multiple possible delimiters

```
$output = preg_split( "/(\^|+)/", "54654561^uo_sgzg@zrgher.com" );
```

-> ("54654561", "uo_sgzg@zrgher.com")

```
$output = preg_split( "/(\^|+)/", "54654561+ghkkgzg@zrgher.com" );
```

-> ("54654561", "ghkkgzg@zrgher.com")

But this regex `"/(\^|+)/"` fails: `PHP Warning:  preg_split(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 3` for some reason, however it's based on this answer [Php multiple delimiters in explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955433/php-multiple-delimiters-in-explode)

this one is working `$output = preg_split("/[\^|+]/", "54654561^MYMED_sgzg@zrgher.com" );` is it the right way to split with multiple delimiters?

**edit** : sorry I just realized it's working like this `$output = preg_split("/(\^|\+)/", "54654561^MYMED_sgzg@zrgher.com" );`

Comment: Delete your question or answer it your self if it's not a question any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's single characters you're trying to match, I would actually opt for the `[\^\+]` option.

Demo: http://ideone.com/ftXSS

The `[]` syntax is called a character class or character set, and it's designed to do specifically what you need.

> A "character class" matches only one out of several characters. To match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`. You could use this in `gr[ae]y` to match either `gray` or `grey`.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html