# Get first 2 sentences in php

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

We have this code that grabs the first two sentences of a paragraph and it works perfect except for the fact that it only counts periods. It needs to get the first two sentences even if they have exclamation points or question marks. This is what we are currently using:

```
function createCustomDescription($string) {
  $strArray = explode('.',$string);
  $custom_desc = $strArray[0].'.';
  $custom_desc .= $strArray[1].'.';

  return htmlspecialchars($custom_desc);
}
```

Any ideas how to also check for question marks and/or exclamation points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php multiple delimiters in explode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955433/php-multiple-delimiters-in-explode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with a regex for the endings that you want with the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE option, this will maintain the punctuation used.

```
function createCustomDescription($string) {
    $split = preg_split('/(\.|\!|\?)/', $string, 3, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $custom_desc = implode('', array_slice($split, 0, 4));

    return htmlspecialchars($custom_desc);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Preserving the punctuation is exactly what we were looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: Great! Seeing as MajicBob nicked my code. Glad its solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
function createCustomDescription($string) 
{

  $strArray  = preg_split('/(\.|\!|\?)/', $string, 3, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);      
  $strArray  = array_slice($strArray, 0, 4);

  return htmlspecialchars(implode('', $strArray));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
function createCustomDescription($string) {
    $strArray = preg_split( '/(\.|!|\?)/', $string);
    $custom_desc = $strArray[0].'.';
    $custom_desc .= $strArray[1].'.';

    return htmlspecialchars($custom_desc);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for locating the end of the first 2 paragraphs and replacing the punctuation with a period, but, we really wanted to keep the existing punctuation which is what @MajicBob came up with. I realize I didn't mention that in the original post, but thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

First replace all ? and ! with a full stop (.) . Then use your usual code 
Using

```
str_replace("?",".",$paragraph);
str_replace("!",".",$paragraph);
```

Then use your code to explode with a (.)