# how do i explode string with multiple sinces

Tags: php, string, output, explode

i have a string like:

```
  $text = 'abc,xyz,wap+web+fbortworme';
```

in my achievement i want to be able explode + or , in the string line so my expected output we look like example:

```
  abc<br/>
  xyz<br/>
  wap<br/>
  web<br/>
  fb<br/>
  tw<br/>
  me<br/>
```

this my tried code:

```
  $text = 'abc,xyz,wap+web+fbortworme';
$plit = explode('+','or',',', $text);

foreach ($plit as $output) 
  {

  echo $output;

  }
```

but i get no output please see here https://ideone.com/8e4eOX

big thanks for your impact in my soluction

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string by multiple delimiters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452777/how-to-split-a-string-by-multiple-delimiters-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php multiple delimiters in explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955433/php-multiple-delimiters-in-explode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split` function to do what you want

```
$text = 'abc,xyz,wap+web+fbortworme';
$splitted = preg_split('/[(or),\+]/', $text);
$splitted = array_filter($splitted); // remove any empty string

print_r($splitted);
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => xyz
    [2] => wap
    [3] => web
    [4] => fb
    [6] => tw
    [8] => me
)
```

And that's your expected output